# Could fire use chemicals other than oxygen as fuel?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, chemistry

Could "fire" exist on a planet that has no oxygen in its atmosphere? If it was using some other chemical as fuel, how would that effect its physical properties, color/appearance, temperature, etc.? And what sort of atmospheres could support such chemical reactions?

Comment: Ever dropped burning magnesium in water or CO2? There are many thousands of such possible reactions, but this seems to be a request for an unconstrained list - those are off-topic here. Can you [edit] to narrow it down to something answerable by the standards you'll find in the [ask] section of the [help], please also take our [tour] for good measure, and add some specific worldbuilding context.

Comment: Sand, glass, and even water will burn with a bright flame in fluorine gas. For example.

Comment: Further reading: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/80478/51094

Comment: Hello @SaturnianThunderDragon, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. This question has a number of problems, which a careful reading of our [tour] and these two pages, [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask], will explain. But if you roll your mouse over the down vote arrow, you'll learn that you're expected to perform basic research before asking your question. A simple Google search for "Oxidizers other than oxygen" includes this article: [Can Fire Burn When There’s No Oxygen?](https://www.scienceabc.com/nature/can-fire-occur-non-oxygenated-reaction.html), which answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Oxygen has no unique properties when it comes to conventional fuels. Oxygen is used because it is so reactive (no gimmicks needed to make it react) and it is so abundant on this planet (easy to obtain). The point of this kind of fuel is to generate lot of heat, and there are many alternatives to oxygen.

See eg: https://www.scienceabc.com/nature/can-fire-occur-non-oxygenated-reaction.html

Comment: You found the same article I did.

Answer (score -1):

I think there's a frame issue here.

Fire, definitionally, is an oxidization reaction and requires Oxygen.

However, there are plenty of Extremely Exothermic reactions that one could substitute with.

Based on the article from Jani, there are non-oxygen oxidizing agents that would be possible candidates.

Just not sure if they would be considered 'Fire'.

Comment: Oxidation reactions do not require oxygen, at least not in any kind of chemistry which is less than 200 years old. For example, both fluorine and chlorine are oxidizing agents; and fluorine is a stronger oxidizing agent than oxygen.

Comment: I have seen a jet of chlorine burning in a hydrogen atmosphere. It looks like fire. I am no sure by what 'definition' it is not fire.

Comment: Wouldn't fire be any sustained exothermic gas-solid aerosol phase reaction?

Comment: "*Fire, definitionally, is an oxidization reaction and requires Oxygen.*" Wikipedia has this to say: "*Oxidation originally implied a reaction with oxygen to form an oxide. Later, the term was expanded to encompass oxygen-like substances that accomplished parallel chemical reactions. Ultimately, the meaning was generalized to include all processes involving the loss of electrons or the increase in the oxidation state of a chemical species*" [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redox#Oxidants).